# How to display any action status on asp.net web page using bootstrap alerts?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a asp.net project. It is not a MVC project.
I have a requirement to display status messages (save succesful, save failed etc) some where on the page.
I am using bootstrap alerts to display the same.
I am using the below code to display the alerts.

```
<div class = "row" style="margin:0 2px 0 2px" >
    <div class="col-md-12" id="AlertNotificationDiv" runat="server">
      <asp:Label id="AlertNotificationBox" runat="server"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the code behind file I am using the following code to set the alerts

```
if (!AlertNotificationDiv.Visible)
    AlertNotificationDiv.Visible = true;
if (!AlertNotificationBox.Visible)
    AlertNotificationBox.Visible = true;

AlertNotificationDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-ms-12 alert alert-success alert-dismissable");
AlertNotificationBox.Text = "Some message comes here";
```

Is this fine or is there any better way to handle the scenario.
The problems I am facing with this approach is.
1. I am not able to provide a functionality where in the alert closes in about 5 sec. With some code I was able to hide the the alert after a few seconds, but if there is any post back for any other action it is appearing again.

Can somebody tell me as to how I can make this alert go after a few seconds and it does not come again until I explicitly make the visibility to true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for auto-close the alert, did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643308/how-to-automatically-close-alerts-using-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at beginning of page_load to reset the message

```
AlertNotificationDiv.Visible = false;
AlertNotificationBox.Text = "";
```

Then on some action where you need to display the alert, set to visible and text to the alert message

Don't see need for setting `AlertNotificationBox.Visible`, because it will be hidden and displayed with the container div.